# Warning: GD extension needs to be loaded for OpenCart to work

Tags: php, opencart, cpanel

How To Solve on Remote Server On OpenCart Installing? Warning: GD extension needs to be loaded for OpenCart to work!

Step:2(Pre-Installation) in Open cart Installation.

Comment: https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/how-to-install-php-gd-library.127773/#post-554957

Answer (score 5):

You have to install the php gd package. If you are using ubuntu, on the terminal type

```
sudo apt-get install php5-gd
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is cPanel server, you will have to recompile Apache and PHP using EasyApache option from WHM to enable support for GD library. Please note that you will need root access of the server to recompile it. If you do not have it, you will have to contact your server administrator to enable support for GD library.

Answer (score 1):

I am using PHP 8 on Windows.

I just uncommented extension=gd in php.ini
xampp\php\php.ini

Comment: Thanks! This solved my problem for Xampp as on 11th July 2022

Answer (score 0):

I'm running php 7.2.14 on Amazon Linux 2 on Amazon Ec2 and this worked for me:

```
$ sudo yum update -y
$ sudo yum install -y php-gd
$ sudo reboot
```

Answer (score 0):

in the window you can config php.ini

find gd in remove ; restart your local server

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

For Windows localhost:
you simply have to go xampp/php/php(configuration settings file type) you have to simply uncommented ;extension=gd and then restart server and after refresh problem will fix on your site